# Save managedObjectContext partly

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsundomanager

I have 3 transaction already in `NSManagedObjectContext`: `A`, `B`, `C`. They were performed / added to context in the same order.

How can I save only the first `A` transaction, but keep unsaved `B`, `C` on context.

`insert A`, `insert B`, `insert C`, `commit A`, ..

Unfortunately `NSManagedObjectContext` can not do `commit A`, but save all the transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missing something. Your goal is to save a specific object, say `A`, only and only if `A`'s data has been committed to the server. Am I wrong?

If this is the case, you can take advantage of `NSOperation` class. Wrap your work (a save to the persistent store or a commit to the server) into an `NSOperation` subclass. Add a dependency between them.

Just an example.

```
let serverOperation : NSOperation = ...
let localOperation : NSOperation = ...
localOperation.addDependency(serverOperation)

let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
operationQueue.addOperations([serverOperation, localOperation], waitUntilFinished: false)
```

Another way could be that the save and commit operations are considered as a unique transaction.

Let me know if something it's not clear.

Comment: *Maybe I missing something. Your goal is to save a specific object, say A, only and only if A's data has been committed to the server.* --- yes, but when you `save`, `B` and `C` will already on context, and I do not want to save `B` and `C`, but want to keep them unsaved on context